# "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'input' referenced before assignment" for nearly every input in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = int(0)
ans1 = int(0)
ans = int(0)  
with open('risk_q.txt') as r:
    for x in range(12): 
        mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in r] 
        ans1 = int(input())             #Error occurs in this line
```

This error occurred with a different input earlier in the code so I got the input before the function and then passed it through the parameter of the function.

Comment: When I create an empty file `risk_q.txt` and run the code I don't get the error you claim to get in the title. Please create a [mre].

Comment: Please post more code, the error implies `input` is used elsewhere, please post the lines where you've typed `input`

Comment: The code, as written, would never produce this error because the entire code is in the global scope, and the compiler wouldn't mark anything as local. Please **always** provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check back through your code.  It appears as though you have used `input` as a variable name, and therefore overwritten the builtin function.

Comment: I have checked through my code with control+f and there is no variable named input, thank you for commenting though

Comment: And you ran your code in a new session?